# Why does is_front_page and is_home always return true for posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

My front page is just a list of the posts separated by category. I'm working on a plugin that get the id of the post but needs to test if the user is currently on the front page:

```
if(is_front_page()){
     do this thing
}
else {
     do this other thing
}
```

problem is, on the post pages it returns true for is_front_page. I tried is_home but get the same result.

Comment: Is_home would definitely be wrong, although it's name *is* misleading.  is_home refers to the post listing page, rather than the actual front page.

Has the blog you're trying this on actually got a front page set in the admin area?  If not that could be your problem.

Comment: in the admin "latest posts" is set as the home page and the index is running loop-home.php

Comment: since I'm not setting a static home page I had assumed "is_home" would return false unless I'm on my home.

Comment: I'm using is_home in the header and it's working as expected.

Comment: had to reset the query... wp_reset_query();

Answer (score 2):

Turns out since the plugin output in the footer I just had to reset the query: wp_reset_query();